# Tensorflow sequential matrix multiplication

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, tensor, attention-model

I have two tensors of the following shapes:

```
tensor1 => shape(?, ?, 100) # corresponds to [batch_size, max_time, embedding_size]
tensor2 => shape(?, 100) # corresponds to [batch_size, embedding_size]
```

What I wish to do is for every `[100] dimensional` vector in `tensor2` obtain a matrix multiplication with corresponding `[max_time, 100] dimensional` matrix in `tensor1` to get `batch_size` number of `max_time` dimensional vectors; which is same as a `[batch_size, max_time] dimensional` matrix.

For those who know: I am basically trying to implement the content based attention over the encoded inputs given by the encoder of a seq2seq model. all the `[max_time]` dimensional vectors are just the attention values that I later softmax.

I am aware that tensorflow provides the `AttentionWrapper` as well as various helpers in the `contrib` package. However, I wish to do this because I am experimenting with the attention mechanism to obtain a hybrid attention mask.

I have tried the `tf.while_loop` but, got stuck in the `?` shape to unroll the loop. A vectorized implementation also doesn't seem very straight forward to me. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is use `tf.matmul` and handle your vectors like 100 * 1 matrices.

```
tensor2 = tf.expand_dims(tensor2, 2)
result = tf.matmul(tensor1, tensor2)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response (helps a lot). I didn't know the `tf.matmul` has a different behavior for arguments that have a `rank  > 2`.